# appengine ChannelFailureException is not thrown in dev

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

AppEngine is supposed to throw ChannelFailureException whenever there is an error in sending message to a channel, e.g. when a channel is not connected.

It seems like the dev server does not throw this exception. It does show a warning in Console:

```
com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.ChannelManager sendMessage
WARNING: Skipping message to unconnected channel: <clientId>
```

this warning seems to be generated by:
    com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.LocalChannelFailureException

**However, the actual exception (i.e. *com.google.appengine.api.channel.ChannelFailureException*) is not thrown**. Does any body know how to test for this exception in development?

Answer (score 1):

In the case where a channel isn't connected and you try to send a message to it, no error is expected to be thrown.

The ChannelFailureException is thrown in cases where you provide a malformed clientid or message, or if there's a problem with the Channel infrastructure such that the message can't be sent.

Comment: ok, so is the above behavior only present in the dev environment? Could you please elaborate on **why the WARNING: Skipping message to unconnected channel: <clientId> is displayed?**. This warning is displayed only when the channel isn't connected (i.e. the user is signed out). The clientId and the message are well-formed. If the user is signed in, the message is sent without warning using the same clientId and message.

Comment: The warning is just informational. It won't happen in production.

Comment: oh ok. so that exception will be thrown when the Channel infrastructure fails. So what's the most we can do when that happens? Should we retry to send the message? And since the exception isn't thrown in dev, I guess the only way to test (if possible) would be to upload and try until it throws that exception?

Comment: You could retry sending if this error happens in production, yes. To test, I'd recommend mocking out the channel module in Python, or ChannelService object in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This state also comes up when you mix up the token and clientId. In my case it was because I was trying to create a

```
message = ChannelMessage(token, message);
```

instead of

```
message = ChannelMessage(clientId, message);
```

where

```
String token = channelService.createChannel(clientId);
```